# Logout or switch user in Windows using Python

Tags: python, windows

I want to write a small program that given a time (in minutes) as input, sleeps in the background for that time, and then forces a return to the "switch user screen" (equivalent to the Winkey+L combination) or logs off a user (may be another user logged in on the same machine).

What functions or libraries in Python could I use for this?

Edit:

- I prefer just a return to the "Switch User" screen rather than actually logging off
- Perhaps there's a simple Windows command to do this, which I could use
- I have Windows XP if that's relevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a simple way of locking a computer using no Python libraries except for ctypes:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation ()
```

Source: [Tim Golden's Python Stuff](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/lock_my_workstation.html)

Answer (score 2):

To switch users, you can use this **Win32 API** function `WTSDisconnectSession(HANDLE hServer, DWORD SessionId, BOOL bWait)`

```
#include "WtsApi32.h"

BOOL OsofemSwitchUser()
{
//Switch User
return WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, TRUE);
}
```

Remember to link it to the `WtsApi32.lib` library.
This will return you to the Switch User screen... Hope this help...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use os.popen or [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to run windows command line for logout.
I think logoff is the command. (According to this [page](http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/09/12/windows-run-commands/))

Comment: logoff sounds good, but I'd prefer just to lock out the user (like Winkey+L)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use windows API, and run by python.
use os.system('logoff'); (or logout, I forget)
it is not tested, because I am using  ubuntu now...